# Oauth 2.0 Authentication within application console(not in browser) is possible or not

Tags: android, oauth, oauth-2.0, dropbox, dropbox-api

In my android app i need to get authentication through Oauth 2.0 for DropBox API. It is done through browser only(redirected to browser and authenticate) . Is it possible to make authentication login page with in my application .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to redirect the user to the Dropbox Login page and then the user must allow your application to access Dropbox in his behalf, so that you can have the OAuth token.By default, the Dropbox API takes you to the browser during authentication, you may implement a Webview within your application and redirect the user within your application itself.

Comment: can u give me some example to implement this?

Comment: If you want not to use the native browser and use a Webview, you will have to skip using the SDK and do it as described 
https://www.dropbox.com/developers/blog/45/using-oauth-20-with-the-core-api

The authentication process runs on the server-side, i.e. on Dropbox. That means that Dropbox defines the course of action for authenticating a user which you as the client have to follow.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/authorize?client_id=<app key>&response_type=code&redirect_uri=<redirect URI>&state=<CSRF token>  in this url what is CSRF token what is the value